# How to create a Block Diagram

Tags: uml

May i know how to draw a Block Diagram for a system/ software development? I searched online and i couldn't find any guidelines or good example.

What should be on the top in Block Diagram?

Should i arrange the Block Diagram based on my Class Diagram (Inheritance, interface, abstract etc)?

Why use Block Diagram?

What does Block Diagram actually show? The process? The component? The overall architecture?

Can anyone please provide me any links regarding Block Diagram if there is any?

Comment: you did not found anything on google to all these questions??

Comment: I found lots of information regarding Block Diagram and i want to make sure which 1 is the correct 1 that i need to follow. Some showed electrical block diagram and others show flow of system using block diagram. I need confirmation on which is suitable for my situation.

Comment: Wow, this question got voted down so badly. If you guys vote down my question, could you guys, at the same time, provide me an answer? I don't mind for my question to be voted down because i want to learn and i have already googled. Is not that i did not do any research before asking. I just need clarification on my understanding towards somthing i know to make sure that it is correct. Anyway, thanks guys

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A block diagram is helpful mainly in the preliminary stages of software development.

A block diagram is similar to a UML package diagram in that it only shows very high level components of the design and how they interact.

What should be on the top? There isn't really a "top" in a block diagram. You may be confusing this with a layered architecture diagram. In a layered architecture diagram, top-level layers are generally the closest to the user.

Should I arrange the block diagram in terms of Inheritance? Not really, the block diagram is supposed to show only the high level interactions of the system. A UML class diagram is where you show the inheritance and interface behaviour.

Why use a block diagram? Primarily because it is easy to partition the system into components for component-based software engineering and because it makes it easy to discuss with clients/managers.

The block diagram generally shows the overall architecture.

This is an example of a layered architecture diagram:
(from http://www.acaltechnology.com/index.php?page=news&id=1577)

[image: Layered architecture - Hardware abstraction layer]

This is an example of a block diagram:
(from https://web.archive.org/web/20121106145142/http://www.simventions.com/whitepapers/uml/3000_borcon_uml.html)

[image: Block Diagram example]

Comment: I think you are right. I must have confused layered architecture diagram with block diagram. Block diagram must be in a package form?

Comment: A block diagram is similar to a package diagram. Personally, I use block diagrams only in the first 5-10 minutes of a design to establish the components I intend to build and how they should interact. After that the block diagram is inadequate to express the system's architecture as it is too simple and high-level. Only exception is when explaining to a client who wants to understand "how" the system works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helps me a lot, however, can you update the link because it is says "404 Not Found"

Comment: @EdisonPebojot Well, it has been over 8 years since I wrote this answer. Changed it to the internet archive as it was back in 2012... Glad it is still of use

Answer (score 1):

The best way to draw a block diagram is using parts and connectors of the Composite Structure UML diagrams.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what **parts** and **connectors** mean?

Comment: I'm guessing you probably meant Component, not Composite.  Composite shows the innards of the objects; Component shows their high-level relationships.